# decrypt data-partition in twrp

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, twrp

I messed up my phone trying to get open-gapps working on CM 13.
I can't even get into my OS only into recovery mode. I tried flashing several CM-Versions, but that doesn't change much.
I think the problem is, that my dalvik is corrupted. My data-partition is encrypted with a 3x3 pattern and TWRP can't decrypt it, so I can't wipe dalvik. I tried several variations of `twrp decrypt`, but they don't work. Now I am trying to flash cryptfs since I found a HowTo, which told me to use this commands:

```
setprop ro.crypto.state encrypted
vdc cryptfs checkpw 'pattern'
mount /dev/block/dm-0 /data
```

The problem is, that cryptfs is not installed. I tried to flash cryptfs, with a custom made zip-file, but it seems, the cryptfs-installation is also trying to write into /data and just aborts, since it can't mount it.

I really like to avoid making a factory-reset before getting my data out.
Any suggestions?
(I have a Sony Xperia M using nicky-cm)

Comment: What ROM with Android version did you use to encrypt data partition? Can you not just flash that ROM?

Comment: The problem is not decrypting, when I start Android. I can decrypt, but after that, the loading screen gets stucked. Same with a CM 12-Rom. After the decryption, it seems to get in a loop(getting pretty hot over time, and using a lot of energy)

Comment: "*My data-partition is encrypted with a 3x3 pattern and TWRP can't decrypt it*" -- can you shed some light on this? Which TWRP version are you using? Does it not provide a [grid to provide pattern](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/119478-device-encrypted-with-4x4-pattern/) for decryption or is TWRP unable to process your pattern successfully?  Have you tried [this technique](http://raerav.com/encrypted-android-device-and-twrp-unlock/) for decryption? Please list whatsoever variation of twrp decrypt you've tried because we can't know about things which you've not mentioned.

Comment: I tried twrp-2.8.7.0-nicki and twrp-3.0.0-0-nicki. They don't provide a grid. I tried the technique you linked. It gives me 01040708. I tried that, I tried 1478, 02050809, 2589, 8523.

Comment: First thing you should do is update to the latest [ 3.0.2-0-nicki ] TWRP
https://twrp.me/devices/sonyxperiam.html
This was what did the trick for me on my nexus

Comment: @AlbinKC I am using the latest version of TWRP.  It doesn't offer me the opportunity to enter a password.  I'm also trying to salvage my encrypted data not the device.  (galaxy s4)  I used a password not a grid to encrypt my data.  Do you have any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> My data-partition is encrypted with a 3x3 pattern and TWRP can't
>   decrypt it

This can be solved by considering the 3x3 grid as the numbers on the keypad. For Example, consider a pattern that looks like the uppercase **L** character.

```
↓ o o  |  1 2 3
↓ o o  |  4 5 6
↓ → →  |  7 8 9
```

here, your password would be 14789